# if-else in one DB trigger vs multiple DB triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have one table with 3 columns, lets say Table A with columns c1,c2 and c3.
now I want to call different APIs when each of the column are updated trough DB Trigger.
Should I use if else conditions or go for multiple DB Triggers each for one column?

Comment: Oracle or Postgres?

Comment: ORACLE SQL. But the concept remains the same right.

Comment: Don't use triggers, use stored procedures to update the data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'd disagree with you as they're trying to update depending on the column being updated.
To get back to the question: I'd recommend creating one trigger with an if-else statement. Alternatively, although not being the best regarding performance, you can create one trigger with no else-if conditions and create a procedure triggered by the trigger, which handles the rest.

Answer (score 0):

One trigger is fine, because you can use the UPDATING clause to determine which columns are being manipulated, eg

```
SQL> create table t ( x int, y int );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values (1,1);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger TRG
  3  before update on t
  4  for each row
  5  begin
  6    if updating('X') then
  7       dbms_output.put_line('I need to call API for X');
  8    end if;
  9
 10    if updating('Y') then
 11       dbms_output.put_line('I need to call API for Y');
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> update t set x = x + 1;
I need to call API for X

1 row updated.

SQL> update t set x = x + 1;
I need to call API for X

1 row updated.

SQL> update t set x = x + 1, y = y+ 1;
I need to call API for X
I need to call API for Y

1 row updated.
```

Having said that, burying business logic in triggers can often be more trouble than its worth. I've discussed that at length here:

https://youtu.be/P1OFbNhgT1k

https://youtu.be/hdU92bsByOQ

so I've a similar stance here to Wernfried